# ¿Rotar un arreglo hacia la derecha con diferente numero de filas y columnas?

Tags: javascript, html5, array, css3, ecmascript-6

me encuentro realizando el típico juego llamado tetris, es bastante divertido, hace poco cree un snake, el cual es mucho mas simple y sencillo, sin embargo, a la hora de rotar las piezas me encontré con un pequeño inconveniente y es el siguiente:

La estructura de las piezas ACTUAL es así:

```
export const shapes = 

[
    [
        [1,1],          //O
        [1,1]
    ],

    [
        [2],            //I
        [2],
        [2],
        [2]
    ],

    [
        [0,3,3],         //S
        [3,3,0]
    ]
]
```

Por supuesto dentro del primer arreglo existen mas formas, no únicamente esas tres, al inicio la estructura era diferente, cada pieza era mas bien rellenada por ceros de tal forma que la mayor parte de las piezas (aquellas que si se rotaban cambiaban la distribuicion de filas y columnas), tuvieran la misma cantidad de filas y columnas, es decir, rellenar los espacios arriba, abajo, izquierda o derecha según se necesitara, un ejemplo de como tenia antes esta estructura es la S, la cual era así:

```
[0,3,3]      //S
[3,3,0]
[0,0,0]      //Fila extra rellenada con ceros para que coincidan filas y columnas
```

Pero me di cuenta que, al hacerlo de esta manera e intentar obtener la izquierda o derecha de algunas de las fichas (Algunas obtenía bien la izquierda y derecha), en otras, con las funciones que había creado daba conflicto y no me funcionaba bien.

Pensando en una solución rápida y sencilla (Ya que ya me había cansado un poco de buscar porque funcionaba bien para obtener tanto el lado de arriba y el lado de abajo con todas las fichas con la anterior estructura (La de rellenar con ceros para que coincidieran filas y columnas), pero no la izquierda y 
y la derecha con algunas), decidí simplemente, no rellenar con ceros donde no se necesitase, quedando finalmente por ejemplo la ficha S así:

```
[0,3,3],        //S
[3,3,0]
```

Esto aplicaría entonces con las demás fichas, excepto con aquellas que el hecho de que roten no afecta las filas y columnas que tengan. Por ejemplo la O:

```
[1,1],
[1,1]
```

Mi pregunta es entonces...

Sabiendo como funciona mi estructura actual...

¿Es posible rotar las fichas hacia la derecha con mi estructura actual?, intente crear una función para eso, pero estoy muy perdido, mi cerebro exploto pensando...

la función solo debería retornar un nuevo arreglo que contiene las nuevas filas y columnas, es decir, si por ejemplo se va a rotar la S:

```
[
     [0,3,3],         //S sin rotar
     [3,3,0]
]
```

Rotación:

```
//Arreglo a retornar
[
     [3,0],         //S rotada a la derecha
     [3,3],
     [0,3]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy buenas tardes!, pues les comento que logre hacer lo dicho!, solo que no se como aplicar esto en sentido anti horario... es decir, rotar 45° hacia la izquierda... aquí la función que lo permite:

```js
function rotateMatrix(shapeForm,rotationDir = "clockwise"){

 let currRows = shapeForm.length;
 let currCols = shapeForm[0].length;
 let transformedArr = [];

 //Nuevo arreglo con las correspondientes filas y columnas nuevas cuando YA ESTE APLICADA la rotación:
 for(let i = 0; i < currCols; i++){

  transformedArr.push([]);

 }

 //Rotación horaria
 for(let j = 0; j < transformedArr.length; j++){

  for(let n = 0; n < currRows; n++){

   transformedArr[j].unshift(shapeForm[n][j]);

  }

 }

 return transformedArr;
  
}

let shapePruebaRotacion = [

  [0,6],   //J
  [0,6],
  [6,6]

];

let shapeRotadaDerecha = rotateMatrix(shapePruebaRotacion);
console.log(shapeRotadaDerecha);
```

Esta función funciona de la siguiente manera:

Primero se obtienen las filas y las columnas actuales que tiene el arreglo original (La forma sin rotar), luego lo que se hace es que con esta información, se crea un nuevo arreglo que contendrá como total de filas las columnas de el arreglo original, el total de columnas del nuevo arreglo no estará definido aun (Es decir, por ahora no nos importa cuantas nuevas columnas contendrá el nuevo arreglo), ya que las columnas serán dinámicas.

Es decir (El numero de columnas incrementara mientras mas filas hallan en el arreglo original), y cada columna nueva del nuevo arreglo sera seteada atravez de dos ciclos for:

En el segundo ciclo for (el que contiene la variable j), se itera atravez de la cantidad de filas del nuevo arreglo.

En el tercer ciclo for (el que contiene la variable n), se iterara atravez de la cantidad de filas del arreglo original.

Luego, por cada fila que halla en el nuevo arreglo, se añadirá a su primera fila (AL INICIO), el primer elemento de la primera fila del arreglo original (Para esto se usa la función unshift), luego se añade al inicio de la primera fila del nuevo arreglo el segundo elemento de la primera fila del arreglo original, luego el tercero de la primera fila del arreglo original y así sucesivamente.

Luego se pasa a la segunda fila del nuevo arreglo y se repite este proceso pero con la segunda fila del arreglo original (por cada uno de sus elementos), esto permite que "Se rote" correctamente la ficha.

Answer (score 2):

Lo unico que se me ocurre es meter cada pieza en un objeto, y que ese objeto tenga las 4 direcciones representadas

```
var s = {
  movible: true,
  abajo: [
     [0,3,3],         //S sin rotar
     [3,3,0]
   ],
  derecha: [
     [3,0],         //S rotada a la derecha
     [3,3],
     [0,3]
   ],
     .... demas objetos
}
```

el movible se me ocurre que si se puede mover accedas a cualquiera de los 4 estados, mientras que si es falso, poner una propiedad llamada forma  y pues que nomas se utilize eso.
Si cambia tu estructura pero no como manejar las propiedades

Comment: Mientras no existan problemas con la RAM considero que esta opción seria la mas práctica: Soluciona el problema de la dirección de las piezas y el de la rotacion: Se colocan las direcciones en un arreglo y simplemente se recorre con un índice, una dirección ascendiente y la otra dirección descendiente (si excede uno de los límites se reinicia desde el otro)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es cambiar las filas y luego hacer una permutación de filas por columnas con `map`

```js
let array = [[0,3,3],         //S sin rotar
             [3,3,0]];

[array[0], array[1]] = [array[1], array[0]];

console.log(array[0].map((col, i) => array.map(row => row[i])));
```

Comment: Voy a probar la función para ver que tal me va en el tetris, dame unos 5 minutos ;3

Comment: Jorge Félix, tambien muchas gracias por tu aporte, es también una forma valida y (Que tambien llegué a pensar), pero no lo hice por cuestion de recursividad.

Comment: Kiko_L funciona casi a la perfección, me esta rotando la pieza es a la izquierda... como sería para rotación a la derecha??

Comment: De hecho, ahora que lo veo, no funciona del todo bien, por lo que estuve mirando, por ejemplo con la L

Comment: No sabía que querías una función para todas las formas. Había entendido que querías rotar la S. Me temo que no hay forma de rotar todas las piezas de una única forma pero podrías hacer una función que tomara como argumentos el array de la pieza y un `id` de pieza y según dicho `id` aplicar una transformación u otra.

Comment: Entiendo... y que tal si por  parte del destructuring usado en esa pieza en especifico, se utiliza el spread operator de cierta forma para lograrlo??